# OpenLayers 3 hasFeatureAtPixel filter for layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am attempting to create a mouse hover event using the following method taken from the official OL3 examples page:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html

I need to trigger the action only when hovering over a particular layer.  Having consulted the official documentation I discovered that you can use a layer filter function with hasFeatureAtPixel, but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
       return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(layer);
        console.log(feature);       
    });
});
```

The console.log calls result in feature objects being given in the console, but no layer objects, these are returned as 'undefined'.  It is the layer objects which I need to test whether the layer is the correct one.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The filter function will receive one argument, the layer-candidate and
>   it should return a boolean value.

[From API Docs.](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#hasFeatureAtPixel)

Let's say you have a layer like:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  name: 'test',
  // ...
});
```

You can add a layer filter function like:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) return;

  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(layer) {
    return layer.get('name') === 'test'; // boolean
  });
  map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Comment: My vector layers don't have names unfortunately, I usually compare layer objects to identify the layers.  Also, isn't the first argument in the layer filter function a feature, not a layer?  This is why I demonstrated a console.out method, because I can't seem to get at the layer from the layer filter function, it comes out as undefined.  I shall try this though, thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't matter the way you will check the layer you want, the question is how implement the layer filter. See updated answer.

Comment: My mistake was using incorrect example code to try and resolve my issue.  The problem was simple, the argument in the filter function is the layer, not the feature as you have demonstrated.  Problem solved.

Comment: @SingleEntity I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the API is rewritten (v4.0.1), the working example is as follows:

```
var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, {
    layerFilter: function (layer) {
        return layer.get('name') === 'test';
    }
});
```

Comment: Man, this really saved my hide today, I was going crazy trying to figure out why it didn't work. It's true it's in the API, but the way of implementing it is not so clear for those who, like me, are not so used to JS.